# Create a spark dataframe column from a user defined function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

This should be trivial - but I'm missing something:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.functions._

val rand = new java.util.Random(42)
val zipUdf = udf( () => 10000 +  rand.nextInt(200))

val zdf = df.withColumn("postalCode",col(zipUdf))
```

Using the `udf` directly is apparently incorrect:

```
found   : org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

What is the magic required?

*Update* : I had already tried the following:

```
 val zdf = df.withColumn("postalCode",zipUdf)
```

The real problem is should be `zipUdf()` not `zipUdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works without a hitch:

```
val someDF = Seq((0, "hello"), (1, "world")).toDF("id", "text")    
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf   
val rand = new java.util.Random(42)
val zipUdf = udf(() => 10000 +  rand.nextInt(200))

someDF.withColumn("postalCode", zipUdf()).show
```

The output for the code above:

```
+---+-----+----------+
| id| text|postalCode|
+---+-----+----------+
|  0|hello|     10130|
|  1|world|     10163|
+---+-----+----------+
```

Using `col()` with `withColumn` is the primary reason for failure.

Comment: Oh - i see what happened I had not had parens `zipUdf()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem (as the error states) is that `zipUdf` is of type `UserDefinedFunction` while the `withColumn` function expects a `Column`. You need to actually call the `zipUdf` function to get a `Column` back, i.e. use `()`:

```
val zdf = df.withColumn("postalCode", zipUdf())
```

Comment: I had neglected the parens.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap it in col(). The below code should work.

```
val zdf = df.withColumn("postalCode",zipUdf())
```

Comment: ah the problem is I had not had parens